# Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError --user cause Permission denied

Tags: python, pip

I did the following steps:

```
> git clone https://github.com/arzwa/wgd.git
> wgd
> pip install --user .
Processing /lustre/work-lustre/team/apps/wgd
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [('/lustre/work-lustre/team/apps/wgd/.git/objects/pack/pack-fe9c4822bc9d5619c65d5b2af95948f607d4c961.idx', '/tmp/pip-req-build-6pf0ie7x/.git/objects/pack/pack-fe9c4822bc9d5619c65d5b2af95948f607d4c961.idx', "[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/tmp/pip-req-build-6pf0ie7x/.git/objects/pack/pack-fe9c4822bc9d5619c65d5b2af95948f607d4c961.idx'"), ('/lustre/work-lustre/team/apps/wgd/.git/objects/pack/pack-fe9c4822bc9d5619c65d5b2af95948f607d4c961.pack', '/tmp/pip-req-build-6pf0ie7x/.git/objects/pack/pack-fe9c4822bc9d5619c65d5b2af95948f607d4c961.pack', "[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/tmp/pip-req-build-6pf0ie7x/.git/objects/pack/pack-fe9c4822bc9d5619c65d5b2af95948f607d4c961.pack'")]
```

What did I miss?

Thank you in advance

Comment: What are you really trying to do here?

Comment: On our HPC I do not have root access and therefore I used `--user` in `pip` in order to install the package in my home directory.

Comment: `> wgd` - is that `cd wgd`? I'd suggest to start over and post the complete output, e.g. `git clone` is supposed to print `Cloning into 'wgd'...`, and pip is supposed to print `Collecting click>=7.0 (from wgd==1.0)`, it's hard to know which parts you've omitted.

Comment: Can you be more precise on  what you have done so we might be able to help @user977828

Comment: I know this is old, but in case it's of use for others, I'm pretty sure this is a bug in [shutil on lustre](https://bugs.python.org/issue24538)